# SQL Server OR precedence clarification?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was reading [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5333/3473) about  *Logical operators OR AND in condition and order of conditions in WHERE*

However I would like to extend this question .

**Question 1 :**

`IF (CONDITION 1) OR (CONDITION 2)`

I'm not talking about `If CONDITION 1 is TRUE, will CONDITION 2 be checked`

But - Is it possible that SQL will select the row based on `condition 2` ( which is the second phrase) rather than `condition 1` which is the first phrase ?

for example :

```
columnA      columnB
  2              2
```

`select * from table where id=columnA or  id=columnB`

Now  , is it possible that I got the row beucuse it evaluated **first** `id=columnB`

**Question 2 :**

this question talks about the `Where` clause. What about Join ?  does these roles also apply

`select * from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.id=Table2.id or Table1.aa = Table2.aa`

- If CONDITION 1 is TRUE, will CONDITION 2 be checked?
- Is it possible that SQL will yield a row based on `condition 2` ( which is the second phrase) rather than `condition 1` which is the first phrase

Comment: I don't understand what distinction you're trying to draw with "yield a row based on..." - could you try to explain a little differently what this distinction is (or would be) and why it matters?

Comment: I'm still not sure. There would appear to be **no** observable difference in the result set. So, what *difference* does it make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the parts of your question asking about yielding rows, so the only part I can answer so far is:

> If CONDITION 1 is TRUE, will CONDITION 2 be checked

It depends. It may, it may not. There's no guarantee of short-circuiting or evaluation order for any parts of the SQL statement.